# Laravel franzose package with latest version 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

I have installed laravel 5.2,

- I can't able to use this package for laravel version 5.2
- This plugin is easy way to integrate Category management
- We can able to create, edit, update and delete a categories by using this package core library files,

Issue i met while installing this package for laravel version 5.2

```
 [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
 Class 'Franzose\ClosureTable\ClosureTableServiceProvider' not found
```

For your reference kindly please check this link:

```
https://github.com/franzose/ClosureTable
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Here you find something on [ask] and how to build a [mcve]

Comment: Sure Aleksej i have updated my questions with some more points to easily can understand my issues